# Java Eclipse MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to get some car lists from my database ,but somehow I keep getting this error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Make' in 'field list'`and I spent more then enough time figuring it out so I'm trying to find an answer here.

Adapter class:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseAdapter2
{
   public CarList getAllCars()
   {
      MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase();
      CarList cars = new CarList();
      try
      {
         myDB.openMySQLDatabase("db", "root", "");

         String sql = "SELECT Make, Model, LicenseNumber, Color, Year," +
                "HorsePower, TimeUntilService, ConsumptionPerKm," +
                "NumberOfSeats, NumberOfDoors, Transmission, ClimateControl, Price"
               + "FROM cars";

         Object[][] result = myDB.returnSQLQueryResult(sql);

         for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
         {
            for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++)
            {
               String make = (String) result[i][j];
               String model = (String) result[i][j];
               String licenseNumber = (String) result[i][j];
               String color = (String) result[i][j];
               int year = (int) result[i][j];
               String horsePower = (String) result[i][j];
               String timeUntilService = (String) result[i][j];
               String consumptionPerKm = (String) result[i][j];
               int numberOfSeats = (int) result[i][j];
               int numberOfDoors = (int) result[i][j];
               String transmission = (String) result[i][j];
               String climateControl = (String) result[i][j];
               int price = (int) result[i][j];

               cars.add(new Car(make, model, licenseNumber, color, year,
                     horsePower, timeUntilService, consumptionPerKm,
                     numberOfSeats, numberOfDoors, transmission,
                     climateControl, price));

            }
         }
      }
      catch (SQLException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            myDB.closeDatabase();
         }
         catch (SQLException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
      return cars;
   }
}
```

The Database itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYGqY.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgotten a white space before the FROM :

```
String sql = "SELECT Make, Model, LicenseNumber, Color, Year," +
                "HorsePower, TimeUntilService, ConsumptionPerKm," +
                "NumberOfSeats, NumberOfDoors, Transmission, ClimateControl, Price "
               + "FROM cars";
```

Edit:
For your ClassCastException, when you want to convert an int to string, use String.valueof(yourInt), more information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Ha, silly mistake. Thanks a lot, although I'm getting another error. I changed all the variables to String. And i still get a error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at DatabaseAdapter2.getAllCars(DatabaseAdapter2.java:24)
 at Test.main(Test.java:10)

Comment: can you update your post with full stacktrace and your car class if you think that's relevant.